# Are old and former always interchangeable

Tags: adjectives

She is my old friend.
She is my former friend.
She is my old business partner.
She is my former business partner.

Comment: A short answer to 'always interchangeable' - ***NO!***

Comment: No: my _old_ grandmother is not my _former_ grandmother!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Both are adjectives, but 'old' [can be used as a noun](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/old?&o=100074&s=t) as well:

> appropriations to care for the **old**.

And not

> appropriations to care for the **former**.

"[Former" comes only before noun](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/former). Say,

> The beautiful old building has been restored to its former glory.

And not

> The beautiful old building has been restored to its old glory.

Furthermore, we can't write "The beautiful former building" as well.

Now, in your example,
"*old friend*" and "*old business partner*" show continuity of friendship and partnership, while "*former friend*" and "*former business partner*" show that once you had a friendship or partnership, but now you don't have the same.

Hope this would help.

Answer (score 4):

In the examples provided, "old" and "former" are not interchangeable.

An "old friend" is a friend from a long time ago.  You can continue to be friends with them.

A "former friend" used to be your friend, but is not any longer.  The friendship might have been recent.

An "old business partner" might be a business partner from a long time ago, or might be an old person that is your business partner.  You can continue to be business partners with them.

A "former business partner" used to be your business partner, but is not any longer.  The partnership might have been recent.